# Why does "shrink volume" not find any empty space?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, drivers

I was trying to shrink one drive (in order to add the space to another one), using Computer Management -> Disk Management. However, it told me that the space for shrinking is 0.

How can that be? The disk is only around half full. What might be the cause of that?

Comment: Which drive are you trying to Shrink? Which roles does the partition have assigned to it according to Disk Management (Boot, System, etc.)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for the putting in the time to help out. It says: Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It also says "Healthy" so I assume this is not a special case error.

Comment: gotcha, yeah, Windows won't let you shrink files with unmovable files that are in the way (boot files, page files, etc.).  Luckily this has already been asked and answered several times on here. :)

Comment: Also: [Can't shrink to available partition volume in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/781985/cant-shrink-to-available-partition-volume-in-windows), [Windows will not shrink my drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/625143/windows-will-not-shrink-my-drive?lq=1), etc.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 OK. Thanks. Those questions didn't come up in the possible duplicates before I posted the question. Thanks for the links.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully they'll get you where you want to be. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for the link to the duplicate. The answer and comments there helped.